# Pixel 4 OEM unlock impossible?

Tags: custom-roms, bootloader-lock, google-pixel-4

My new Pixel 4 just arrived, and I want to install LineageOS on it. Problem is, the OEM Unlock toggle is disabled (greyed out).

It's not a carrier-locked device or anything like that (purchased from a Dutch retailer).

I've tried a bunch of "fixes", mostly various combinations of factory reset, with and without WiFi or SIM, the `adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 com.android.phone` command, etc.

Are there any other options, like sideloading a custom recovery (if that's even possible)? Or is there a chance it will become available after 7 days as I've read somewhere?

Comment: Based on [existing questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/233310), looks like there are Pixel devices (particularly refurbished) that are bootloader locked. I'm afraid this is also one of them.

Comment: As original Pixel 4 devices can be bootloader unlocked the phone you bought is not what you could expect by the "Pixel 4 " product description (unless the locked bootloader was explicitly mentioned). Usually this should allow you to send back the phone and get back your money (most country has this in their consumer protection law).

Comment: @Robert Yes, here you can return things for any reason within a set period (unless damaged in which case warranty applies). Returned it and got a Galaxy S10e instead, which unlocked no problem.